# What does it mean to "include all the limit points"

Tags: real-analysis

In our analysis class, we were said that a closed interval is an interval which "includes all of its limit points". What does it mean by "includes all of its limit points"?

1. What I know about closed interval is that it contains its 2 endpoints.
2. What I know about limit points is that, a point in an interval is called a limit point if there exist a sequence, all of whose term belong to that interval, converges to that point.

Comment: It means that, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of points in the Interval which converges, then the limit point is also contained in the interval.  For instance, the open interval $(0,1)$ in the real numbers is not closed because the sequence $\{\frac 1n\}$ converges to $0$ but $0$ is not in the open interval.

Comment: For an interval, the limit points are precisely the points in the interval along with the finite endpoints.  This is something that you may want to prove for yourself: the set of limit points of $[a,b]$ is $[a,b]$, the set of limit points of $(a,b)$ is also $[a,b]$, the set of limit points of $(a,\infty)$ is $[a,\infty)$, etc.

Comment: A warning: there are two definitions of ‘limit point’ in the literature. The one that you've stated here, also called ‘adherent point’ or ‘closure point’, is used more often in French. The other one, also called ‘accumulation point’ or ‘cluster point’, is used more often in English. This one requires that all of the terms of the sequence have to be distinct from the point in question. (So every accumulation point is an adherent point, but not always conversely.) For intervals, this only matters for a trivial interval $[a,a]$; $a$ is an adherent point but not an accumulation point.

Comment: Note that $[4,+\infty)$ and even $(-\infty,+\infty)$ are examples of closed intervals. That is, they contain all their limit points.  Presumably including these is why the definition did not refer to "two endpoints" or "left and right endpoints" instead.

Comment: There is a flaw in your understanding of limit points - namely that they are points *in the interval*. There is no such requirement. A limit point of a set is any point that is the limit of a sequence that lies in the set. The limit point itself could be outside. For example, that is exactly the case for $(0,1)$. Both $0$ and $1$ are the limits of sequences within the interval, but they themselves are not in the interval. $(0,1)$ is not closed. Note that "closed" is definable this way for *any* set, not just intervals.

Answer (score 0):

What you stated is correct.
All the points in an interval are limit points, since you can take a sequence in the interval that converges to it. However, even if your interval is open (i.e. it does not have one or both the endopoints), you can find a sequence in your interval converging to one of the two endpoints.

For example, if you have the interval $(1,4]$ (i.e. closed on the right but open on the left), you can find a sequence belonging to the interval which converges to $1$. It is sufficient to take $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$, because $a_n \in (1,n] \ \forall \ n$ and $a_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

It is just a more general way of saying that the interval contains the endpoints. In fact, this notion can be generalized and you can consider the closure of sets where more points are "missing": for instance, the closure of an open interval where we remove an intern point is still all the closed interval, included the two end-points and the internal point priorly removed. If you say that the closure of this interval with $3$ missing points is just the same set with endpoints, you miss the removed internal point. With this definition by sequences, you are sure to take all these missing points.